# Weyl gauge variant such as $A_2=0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

I believe that choosing $A_2 = 0$ instead of $A_0=0$ in solving the wave equation in electrodynamics would imply that our physical polarizations, for a wave propagating in the $\vec k = (0,0,k)$ direction, would give

$$\epsilon_1 = (1,0,0,0),\quad \epsilon_2=(0,1,0,0)$$

where we used the other gauge-fixing condition $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu} = 0$ along with $A_{\mu}(x) = \epsilon_{\mu} e^{ik\cdot x}$. Of course, this should be physically equivalent to picking $A_0 = 0$.

Is there a difference in physical interpretation of $\epsilon_{1,2}$ above compared with $\epsilon_{\pm} = (0, 1, \pm i, 0)$ as usual?

Does this just amount to a notational difference?

Answer (score 3):

Choosing a component of $\mathbf{A}$ to be $0$ is known as the [axial gauge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/313652/axial-gauge-and-maxwell-equations). It's also mentioned as a valid choice for quantization in [Weinberg's "The Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol I"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/the-quantum-theory-of-fields/22986119910BF6A2EFE42684801A3BDF).

The upside part of choosing $A_0=0$ (Weyl gauge) or $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}=0$ (Coulomb) is that then the two basis vectors of $\mathbf{A}$ are the same as the polarization vectors that are the basis for $\mathbf{E}$. When you pick a component of $\mathbf{A}$ to be zero, and the wave isn't propagating along the direction of the chosen component, then the basis for $\mathbf{A}$ won't be the same as the basis for $\mathbf{E}$. By the usual definition, the polarization is defined by what plane the electric field is oscillating in (if linear).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of terminology. I've edited my title. So it sounds like the difference in choosing an axial gauge and Weyl gauge is essentially notation; the latter is more convenient because it coincides with physical polarization?

Comment: @Dwagg That's true of all gauges - they give the same answer (electric and magnetic fields), they just have different situations where one may be more convenient than another.